# Why is my site reputation reported to be lower than the reputation I have (excluding the 100 points bonus)

Tags: support, reputation

On Area 51, my site reputation is reported to be 898, while from my drupal.SE account page I get it is 1077. The difference between 1077 and 1178 (my actual reputation) is the 101 bonus points I get because I associated two different accounts.
Why is there any difference between my site reputation, and my actual reputation?

I suspect the difference is caused by the data being cached from Area 51 in different ways; for other users I see there is a difference between the site reputation and the reputation showed close to the gravatar, but the difference is normally 10 points (and not 280).

**Update:** The difference between the two reputations is less evident, and probably doesn't exist anymore; I cannot know for sure, as my site reputation is now reported to the 1K.
Still, it could be interesting to know why there is such difference for two values that should be equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reputation on area 51 is cached. I believe it's updated once per day. So it will always be a bit out of sync.

Comment: I guess I was more surprised that my site reputation was different from the reputation reported close to my gravatar in the same page (`http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2978/drupal-answers`); when one was reported to be higher than 1000, the other one (the site reputation) was still showing a value lower than 1000 (and higher than 800).